# ASP Net Core 2.2 Session lost after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session-cookies, session-state

I have the following session config in Startup.cs

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

            // Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
     }
```

Everything works fine and the session keeps it Session Id and data. I'm putting some booking info there. Then I redirect a user to payment page. After successful payment the user is redirected back to my site via POST to PaymentController Success action.

Obviously, this POST request from payment platform doesn't contain session cookies, so I just do RedirectToAction("ContinueBooking","Payment") inside PaymentController Success action.

After redirect to action - the browser sends session cookies but the session 
 seems to be lost at this time and a new session Id assigned, all data is lost. Is there any way to prevent this ? Or should I just use database to store data between redirects in my case (i can bypass some parameters through payment terminal)?

Comment: exist  app.UseSession(); in Configure method in startup?

Comment: @hassan.ef sure

Comment: Show the actual controller code.

Comment: Does it take more than 10 seconds before it comes back to your site after the successful payment? You have set the `options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);`. Try increasing it to say 60sec and see if it behaves in the same manner. Also, I guess, you are just testing on your local machine and not behind the load balancer. If your application is behind the load balancer, you would need to use the `DataProtection` API to allow the application to read the session cookie from a central location.

Comment: @ShahzadHassan no it;s a single machine and interval was increased, but nothing helps.

Comment: @ChrisPratt the PaymentController::Success has the only one line __return RedirectToAction("ContinueBooking", "Hotel");__ The session works fine but it's lost after that post-redirect-get from payment system.

Comment: I solved it problem with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50425129/2238515

Comment: @CleverAlmeida thanks. In my case I need consent cookies. For me the issues was fixed by setting AddSession(x=> x.Cookie.HttpOnly=true; x.Cookie.IsEssentialTrue=true;  options.IdleTimeout = Somebigvalue)

Comment: @lavrik Nice to know !!

Comment: for me its not working. any other solution? i have added isessential true but still app redirect to login page after payment

can anyone help :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61500021/net-core-2-2-application-lost-session-after-redirection-from-payment-integratio

Answer (score 3):

If both apps are on same server then both will be same cookie and first cookie will be overwritten by the payment app's session cookie. To avoid this customize the cookie name:

`services.AddSession(opt =>
{ 
    opt.Cookie.Name = "MySessionCookie";
});`

Comment: Thanks, solved issue I was having with authorization cookie. Ended up, in development, was being overwritten when redirecting between different ports.

Comment: This was the one for me. I was trying to implement 2FA with Duo and every time Duo redirected the browser back to my app endpoint the session was empty so I couldn't verify the response. I'd tried all sorts of reasonable-sounding configuration options for the session cookie, but this was the one that finally made the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same scenario, i need to redirect to another site (identity gateway), and this site post returns response identification with http post.

For me, with .net core 3.1 for create session cookie with samesite none i need to use **options.Cookie.SecurePolicy**.

Without this, no cookie is created..

```
services
    .Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // not necessary
        //options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    })
    .AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest; // this is the key
    })
```