# How to render a string to Layout.cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have a method that returns a string in HomeController.

```
public string MyLocation()
{
    return "NYC";
}
```

I am trying to display the returned string in Nav Item of my `_Layout.cshtml` file inside `<p>` tag.

```
<li>
    <a href="#"> <p font-size:14px">  </p> </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not send data to _Layout page ie.(Master page).

> Store your location in the session variable and access it in master
>   page as follows:

```
public string MyLocation()
   {
    Session["MyLocation"]="NYC";
    return "NYC";
   }
```

and `_Layout` Page will be:

```
     <li>
         <a    href="#"> 
            <p font-size:14px">  
                 @HttpContext.Current.Session["MyLocation"].ToString()   
            </p>
         </a> 
    </li>
```

This might help you.

Comment: it says. the name session doesnt exist in current context.

Comment: Check System namespace imported or not. It should be work

Comment: i think this method is for .NET framework, i am using core and its not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50425129/10759381 check this. It may help you

Answer (score 1):

A Layout file knows nothing about the Views (.cshtml files) that use it, and the Views also know nothing about the Layout file, except its name.

The proper way to connect the two is as follows:

**(1)** Have **_Layout.cshtml** contain a **`@RenderBody()`** statement. This is where the output that is generated by the Views will appear.

**(2)** Have your View-file reference the layout file by its name, also preferrably make it use a `Model` class, and make it render partial HTML:

```
// file Views/Location/MyLocation.cshtml

@model YourProject.Models.Location   // See part (3) below

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h2>My Location</h2>

<div>
    City: @(Model.City)
</div>
```

**(3)** Define the model class:

```
// file Models/Location.cs

namespace YourProject.Models
{
    public class Location
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**(4)** Have the Action-method in the Controller create a Model object, and send it to the View:

```
// file Controllers/LocationController.cs

namespace YourProject.Controllers
{
    public class LocationController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult MyLocation()
        {
            var model = new Location { City = "NYC" };
            return View(model); // This will start MyLocation.cshtml and pass 'model' as a parameter into it
        }
    }
}
```

More info here:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_razor_layout_views.htm
- https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/layout

---

As an alternative you could use **[`ViewBag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview#weakly-typed-data-viewdata-viewdata-attribute-and-viewbag)**. You can then omit the `Location` Model class, but you will also lose all the advantages of Intellisense and compile-time validity checking.

```
// file Views/Location/MyLocation.cshtml

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

Location: @(ViewBag.Location) <i>(from ViewBag)</i>
```

```
// file Controllers/LocationController.cs

namespace YourProject.Controllers
{
    public class LocationController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult MyLocation()
        {
            ViewBag.Location = "NYC";
            return View(); // This will start MyLocation.cshtml without a 'model'.
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a ViewBag approach, a Model approach, or even combine the two.

You can also use ViewBag in the _Layout file, but then you have to make sure that every Controller action method supplies the value in `ViewBag` because it is **not** preserved between calls.

Comment: I am trying to render it into _Layout.cshtml file not in Location.cshtml ...

Comment: See the alternative that I just added.