# HttpContext getting null when returning from WebPaymentAPI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpcontext

I'm using a webpayment api solution on my website.
When the API asks my OnPost() function and returning to my back url my HttpContext seems to be replaced by an other HttpContext.

I can't get my HttpContext.Session back, all datas are removed.

(I'm already using services.addSession() & app.useSession())

Code of my OnPost Method from the VerifPoints.cshtml page

```
public void OnPost()
    {
        Utilisateur = Utilisateur.Current(HttpContext); //Calling a HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserID")   /!\ THIS IS NULL /!\


        string json = get_web_content("URLOFMYWEBPAYMENTAPI" + Request.Form["code"]);

        dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        if (array.status == "success")
        {
            int montant = array.virtual_currency;
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Pbs", montant);

            Response.Redirect("/compte/recharger_points");
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Pbs", 0);

            Response.Redirect("/compte/recharger_points");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the solution of this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770491/session-variable-value-is-getting-null-in-asp-net-core solve your issue ?

Comment: No it's does not solving my issue at all