# .NET 6 Session TimeOut

Tags: c#, session, timeout, .net-6.0

I am trying to set the session timeout to 30 mins in .NET 6.
I added the following code for it.

```
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

It is not working and the session is expiring in a few minutes.

Comment: How do you check that session has expired? Also note that default session timeout is 20.

Comment: I perform an activity and start a stopwatch. After 11 min, I refresh the current page, and its redirects to the login screen.

Comment: This does not prove that session cookie has expired. Can you please provide a full [mre]?

Comment: If you are redirecting to login screen after some idle time it should be the issue of session cookie.

Comment: It can be an issue of auth cookie

Answer (score 0):

When session is expired, the server will delete all session variables set on login and there is no way to see if it has been expired from client side (one of the many reasons on why I switched from `Sessions` to `JsonWebTokens`).

To use session, add following code in your `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

    // make the session cookie Essential
    // so that session variable is not null
    // check this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64984796/19112855
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

app.UseSession(); // before app.UseAuthentication(); and after app.UseRouting();
```

To manually delete all session variables, call this in your controller `HttpContext.Session.Clear();`

Comment: Codingwiz, worked locally but not on the server. I find that server has its own configurations. It might be the issue as it is working fine in local IIS.